# 3 bit modify on 5 variables at any offset

Tags: c

I want to know if there is a better way to modify a 3 bit chunks of any of 5 variables, 4 are int16 and 1 is int8.

for example:

```
int16 leds1 = 0b0100000000100101;
//color white=111
put_color_white_in_offset_of_9_bits_Rotuine_without_modifying_other_bits();
leds1 = 0b0100111000100101;

//leds1 old value: 0b0100000000100101
//leds1 new value: 0b0100111000100101
```

That variables stores a 3 bit dept RGB color of 24 LEDs and then they are shiftOut to a shift register 74hc595, my actual code that works, but is not efficient i think, is this:

```
/*
BGR RGB DEC COLOR
000 000 0   black
100 001 1   blue
010 010 2   green
110 011 3   cyan (blue + green)
001 100 4   red
101 101 5   magenta (red + blue)
011 110 6   yellow (red + green)
111 111 7   white (red + blue + green)
*/
void setLed(int8 nled, int16 color)
{
    switch(nled)
    {
        case 0:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<0);
        leds1 = (leds1 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<0);
            break;
        case 1:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<3);
        leds1 = (leds1 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<3);
            break;
        case 2:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<6);
        leds1 = (leds1 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<6);
            break;
        case 3:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<9);
        leds1 = (leds1 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<9);
            break;
        case 4:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<12);
        leds1 = (leds1 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<12);      
            break;
        case 5:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<15);
        leds1 = (leds1 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<15);
        bit_mask16 = (7>>1);
        leds2 = (leds2 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color>>1);
            break;
        case 6:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<2);
        leds2 = (leds2 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<2);
            break;
        case 7:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<5);
        leds2 = (leds2 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<5);
            break;
        case 8:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<8);
        leds2 = (leds2 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<8);
            break;
        case 9:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<11);
        leds2 = (leds2 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<11);
            break;
        case 10:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<14);
        leds2 = (leds2 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<14);
        bit_mask16 = (7>>2);
        leds3 = (leds3 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color>>2);
            break;
        case 11:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<1);
        leds3 = (leds3 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<1);
            break;
        case 12:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<4);
        leds3 = (leds3 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<4);
            break;
        case 13:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<7);
        leds3 = (leds3 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<7);
            break;
        case 14:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<10);
        leds3 = (leds3 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<10);
            break;
        case 15:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<13);
        leds3 = (leds3 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<13);
            break;
        case 16:
        bit_mask16 = (7);
        leds4 = (leds4 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color);
            break;
        case 17:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<3);
        leds4 = (leds4 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<3);
            break;
        case 18:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<6);
        leds4 = (leds4 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<6);
            break;
        case 19:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<9);
        leds4 = (leds4 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<9);
            break;
        case 20:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<12);
        leds4 = (leds4 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<12);
            break;
        case 21:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<15);
        leds4 = (leds4 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<15);
        bit_mask8 = (7>>1);
        leds5 = (leds5 & (~bit_mask8)) | (color>>1);
            break;
        case 22:
        bit_mask8 = (7<<2);
        leds5 = (leds5 & (~bit_mask8)) | (color<<2);
            break;
        case 23:
        bit_mask8 = (7<<5);
        leds5 = (leds5 & (~bit_mask8)) | (color<<5);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds1);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds1>>8);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds2);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds2>>8);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds3);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds3>>8);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds4);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds4>>8);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds5);
//! output_bit(LAT, HIGH);
//! output_bit(LAT, LOW); 
    LATA2 = 1;  //FASTER THAN OUTPUT_BIT
    LATA2 = 0;  //FASTER THAN OUTPUT_BIT
}
```

the full code is this:

```
#include "HEADER_4620.h" //FUSES & OSC FREQ 32Mhz & ADC 10 BITS 
#include "Puertos.c"    //DEFINITIONS FOR REGISTERS LATx, PORTx & TRISx

#define LED PIN_D7                  // LED PIN
#define FLASH Output_Toggle(LED)    // FLASH MACRO

//!#define DAT PIN_A0
//!#define CLK PIN_A1
//!#define LAT PIN_A2

#define DAT LATA0   //74HC595 DS (DATA) PIN
#define CLK LATA1   //74HC595 SH_CP (DATA CLOCK) PIN
#define LAT LATA2   //74HC595 ST_CP (LATCH CLOCK)PIN

#define LSBFIRST 1
#define MSBFIRST 0

#define HIGH 1
#define LOW 0

#define black 0
#define blue 1
#define green 2
#define cyan 3
#define red 4
#define magenta 5
#define yellow 6
#define white 7
/*
BGR RGB DEC COLOR
000 000 0   black
100 001 1   blue
010 010 2   green
110 011 3   cyan (blue + green)
001 100 4   red
101 101 5   magenta (red + blue)
011 110 6   yellow (red + green)
111 111 7   white (red + blue + green)
*/
//PROTOTYPES
void shiftOut(int16 dataPin, int16 clockPin, int8 bitOrder, int8 val);
void setLed(int nled, int16 color);
void test_sequence(int16 t);

//GLOBAL VARS
volatile int16 leds1=0, leds2=0, leds3=0, leds4=0, bit_mask16 = 0;
volatile int8 leds5=0, bit_mask8 = 0;

//############################      MAIN    ###################################
void main()
{
    LATC5 = 0;
    LATA = 0;

    TRISA = 0;
    TRISC = 0b10000000;// C7 AS INPUT FOR RS232 RX

    setup_comparator(NC_NC_NC_NC);
    set_analog_pins(NO_ANALOGS);


    do
    {
    test_sequence(10);
    } while(TRUE);

}//main 

//############################      FUNCTIONS   ###############################

void shiftOut(int16 dataPin, int16 clockPin, int8 bitOrder, int8 val)
{
    int8 i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
//!     if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST)
//!         output_bit(dataPin, !!(val & (1 << i)));
//!     else    
//!         output_bit(dataPin, !!(val & (1 << (7 - i))));
//!         output_bit(clockPin, HIGH);
//!         output_bit(clockPin, LOW);

        //FASTER ROUTINE, IGNORING FIRST 3 PARAMETERS
        LATA0 = !!(val & (1 << (7 - i))); // WHY DOUBLE "!" OPERATOR ?
        LATA1 = 1;
        LATA1 = 0;

        //UPDATE:
        //DOUBLE LOGIC NEGATION OPERATOR IS USED TO CONVERT 0 TO 0
        //AND ANY OTHER NUMBER TO 1, It is the same as:
        //x != 0 ? 1 : 0
        //SOURCE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191446/confused-by-use-of-double-logical-not-operator
    }
}

/*
BGR RGB DEC COLOR
000 000 0   black
100 001 1   blue
010 010 2   green
110 011 3   cyan (blue + green)
001 100 4   red
101 101 5   magenta (red + blue)
011 110 6   yellow (red + green)
111 111 7   white (red + blue + green)
*/
void setLed(int8 nled, int16 color)
{
    switch(nled)
    {
        case 0:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<0);
        leds1 = (leds1 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<0);
            break;
        case 1:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<3);
        leds1 = (leds1 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<3);
            break;
        case 2:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<6);
        leds1 = (leds1 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<6);
            break;
        case 3:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<9);
        leds1 = (leds1 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<9);
            break;
        case 4:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<12);
        leds1 = (leds1 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<12);      
            break;
        case 5:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<15);
        leds1 = (leds1 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<15);
        bit_mask16 = (7>>1);
        leds2 = (leds2 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color>>1);
            break;
        case 6:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<2);
        leds2 = (leds2 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<2);
            break;
        case 7:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<5);
        leds2 = (leds2 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<5);
            break;
        case 8:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<8);
        leds2 = (leds2 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<8);
            break;
        case 9:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<11);
        leds2 = (leds2 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<11);
            break;
        case 10:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<14);
        leds2 = (leds2 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<14);
        bit_mask16 = (7>>2);
        leds3 = (leds3 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color>>2);
            break;
        case 11:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<1);
        leds3 = (leds3 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<1);
            break;
        case 12:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<4);
        leds3 = (leds3 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<4);
            break;
        case 13:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<7);
        leds3 = (leds3 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<7);
            break;
        case 14:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<10);
        leds3 = (leds3 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<10);
            break;
        case 15:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<13);
        leds3 = (leds3 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<13);
            break;
        case 16:
        bit_mask16 = (7);
        leds4 = (leds4 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color);
            break;
        case 17:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<3);
        leds4 = (leds4 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<3);
            break;
        case 18:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<6);
        leds4 = (leds4 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<6);
            break;
        case 19:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<9);
        leds4 = (leds4 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<9);
            break;
        case 20:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<12);
        leds4 = (leds4 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<12);
            break;
        case 21:
        bit_mask16 = (7<<15);
        leds4 = (leds4 & (~bit_mask16)) | (color<<15);
        bit_mask8 = (7>>1);
        leds5 = (leds5 & (~bit_mask8)) | (color>>1);
            break;
        case 22:
        bit_mask8 = (7<<2);
        leds5 = (leds5 & (~bit_mask8)) | (color<<2);
            break;
        case 23:
        bit_mask8 = (7<<5);
        leds5 = (leds5 & (~bit_mask8)) | (color<<5);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds1);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds1>>8);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds2);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds2>>8);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds3);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds3>>8);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds4);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds4>>8);
    shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,leds5);
//! output_bit(LAT, HIGH);
//! output_bit(LAT, LOW); 
    LATA2 = 1;  //FASTER THAN OUTPUT_BIT
    LATA2 = 0;  //FASTER THAN OUTPUT_BIT
}


void test_sequence(int16 t)
{
        for(int x=0;x<24;x++)
        {
            setLed(x,red);
            delay_ms(t);
            //setLed(x,black);
        }
        for(x=24;x>0;x--)
        {
            setLed(x-1,green);
            delay_ms(t);
            //setLed(x-1,black);
        }
        for(x=0;x<24;x++)
        {
            setLed(x,blue);
            delay_ms(t);
            //setLed(x,black);
        }   
        for(x=24;x>0;x--)
        {
            setLed(x-1,cyan);
            delay_ms(t);
            //setLed(x-1,black);
        }
        for(x=0;x<24;x++)
        {
            setLed(x,magenta);
            delay_ms(t);
            //setLed(x,black);
        }
        for(x=24;x>0;x--)
        {
            setLed(x-1,yellow);
            delay_ms(t);
            //setLed(x-1,black);
        }
        for(x=0;x<24;x++)
        {
            setLed(x,white);
            delay_ms(t);
            //setLed(x,black);
        }
        for(x=24;x>0;x--)
        {
            setLed(x-1,black);
            delay_ms(t);
            //setLed(x-1,white);
        }
}
```

Here are attached a schematic and pin configurations that can be helpful to understand what I'm trying to do.

[LED & 74HC595 PINS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUh8v.png)

[SCHEMATIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XssGi.png)

Maybe using 9 variables of 8 bits each one instead of 4 variables of 16 bit & 1 variable of 8 bit, is a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with 3x32 bits. shiftOut() needs to get a long and the bit count. But I don't know, how shiftOut addresses the correct pins. It seems, all pins have to be set with an internal counter/shifter?

```
void setLed(int8 nled, int16 color)
{    
  int32 bits[3];
  int idx=led/10;
  int bitp=(led%10)*3;
  color&=7;
  bits[idx] = (bits[idx] & ~(7<<bitp)) | (color<<bitp);

  shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,bits[0],30);
  shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,bits[1],30);
  shiftOut(DAT,CLK,MSBFIRST,bits[2],12);
}
void shiftOut(int16 dataPin, int16 clockPin, int8 bitOrder, int32 val, int16 bitcnt)
{
  int8 i;
  int32 mask = 1 << (bitcnt-1);
  for (i = 0; i < bitcnt; i++, mask>>=1)  {
    LATA0 = !!(val & mask); // WHY DOUBLE "!" OPERATOR ?
    // double logical not ->  0 becomes 0  any value becomes 1
    LATA1 = 1;
    LATA1 = 0;
  }
}
```